# Segment Intersection

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Here is a question from CLRS. 
A disk consists of a circle plus its interior and is represented by its center point and radius. Two disks intersect if they have any point in common. Give an O(n lg n)-time algorithm to determine whether any two disks in a set of n intersect.

Its not my home work. I think we can take the horizontal diameter of every circle to be the representing line segment. If two orders come consecutive, then we check the length of the distances between the two centers. If its less than or equal to the sum of the radii of the circles, then they intersect.

Please let me know if m correct.

Comment: Are the disks placed in a straight line?

Comment: Try to calculate if your approach has complexity O(n lg n) and post your solution.

Comment: Investigate sweep-line algorithms for finding intersections of line segments, see if they can be adapted to disks.

Comment: no, the disks are not placed in a straight line

Comment: @MaxLeske I think my algo works in O(nlgn). I'll maintain a sorted array with their x coordinates. I'll enter a disk in the tree when the starting end occurs. Now when another start point occurs, we check the distance with the neighbouring circles. The disks can be maintained in a balanced BST. So, time O(nlgn)

Comment: Your algo from the comment can indeed work in O(n log n). Does it work at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a Voronoi diagram for disk centers. This is an O(n log n) job.

Now for each edge of the diagram take the corresponding pair of centers and check whether their disk intersect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a k-d tree with the centres of the circles.
2. For every circle `(p, r)`, find using the k-d tree the set `S` of circles whose centres are nearer than `2r` from `p`.
3. Check if any of the circles in `S` touches the current circle.

I think the average cost for this algorithm is O(NlogN).

The logic is that we loop over the set `O(N)`, and for every element get a subset of elements near `O(NlogN)`, so, a priori, the complexity is `O(N^2 logN)`. But we also have to consider that the probability of two random circles being less than `2r` apart and not touching is lesser than `3/4` (if they touch we can short-circuit the algorithm).

That means that the average size of `S` is probabilistically limited to be a small value.

Comment: What do you mean by "But we also have to consider that the probability of two random circles being less than 2r apart and not touching is lesser than 3/4". If the two centers are less than 2r apart, then they will touch

Comment: You have two circles and two radius (`r` and `r2`). You know nothing about `r2`. In the worst case `r2` may be `0` and then the probability of both circles not touching becomes 3/4. So this is an upper limit for the probability of both circles not touching.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve the problem:

1. Divide the plane using a grid whose diameter is that of the biggest circle.
2. Use a hashing algorithm to classify the grid cells in N groups.
3. For every circle calculate the grid cells it overlaps and the corresponding groups.
4. Get all the circles in a group and...

   1. Check if the biggest circle touches any other circle in the group.
   2. Recurse applying this algorithm to the remaining circles in the group.

This same algorithm implemented in scala: https://github.com/salva/simplering/blob/master/touching/src/main/scala/org/vesbot/simplering/touching/Circle.scala